# emacs-snapshot: Could not find simple.el or simple.elc

Tags: emacs-snapshot

I tried to install emacs-snapshot through their PPA on a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-elisp/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install emacs-snapshot
```

But when i try to start it, it gives me this error:

```
emacs-snapshot
Warning: Could not find simple.el or simple.elc
Cannot open load file: No such file or directory, warnings
```

I have also tried running it as sudo, and the same thing happens. 
I do not have an .emacs.d/ folder, so it should just run as vanilla.

Do anyone have any idea how i can make it work?

Comment: The same thing happened to me today. I stupidly updated the emacs-snapshot package (i'm on linux mint 17.2) and i got this error.

Comment: I think using stable release of Emacs is better idea, compile emacs is easy, for example: https://github.com/favadi/build-emacs.

Comment: @favadi is correct. Build emacs from source and avoid distros.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue. It looks all el-files were placed into incorrect directory. I'm not sure but I found 2 directories in /usr/share/emacs for 25.0.50 and 25.1.50. The version of my emacs is 25.0.50 and I think it's the latest version but all required files in directory 25.1.50. I just renamed original 25.0.50 directory and created symlink with name 25.0.50 to point to 25.1.50. It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same phenomenon today and Googled the message and I reached here.
The workaround that Vitaly has worked, but I wonder why I could install Emacs just by `$ sudo apt install emacs` before but I could not then.

I asked the same question in the Japanese Stack Overflow and a person told me that simple.elc is included in the dependent library `emacs25-common`.

So I ran `$ sudo apt install emacs25-common` and then I could fix the problem.

Maybe it was because I installed the older Emacs before.
I thought I have purged the old Emacs but maybe the old libraries have remained somehow.
ANd when I re-installed emacs25-common, I could overwrite the old library with the correct one so I could fix it.

Pseudo code:
1) install Emacs with `$ sudo apt install emacs`
2) if succeed => congrats! your work has done
3) else if you got the massage `simple.elc missing` then `$ sudo apt install emacsXX-core` (where XX is version number)

Hope this helps.